# Subviews are not fit inside UIScrollView when using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

This is my view hierarchy,

```
UIView
 UIScrollView
   UIView
     UIView
     UIButton
   UIView
     UIView
     UIButton
   UIView
     UIView
     UIButton
   ...
```

I have set Leading / Trailing and Top/Bottom space constraints to `UIScrollView`. But don't know why, inside contents are more than `UIScrollView`s width? Its moving like all around (I don't know how to explain this?)... Is this an issue of `contentSize`? If so, that I haven't set any where. Is it required to set it? Or any constraints I missed to add?

<sub>P.S. I'm pretty new to **Autolayout**.</sub>

Comment: did u constraint the scroll view width and height ?

Comment: if inside contents are more than the scroll view width, then you might missing the constrainst setup for the inside contents

Comment: Add a `UIView` inside `Scrollview` to hold all other `UIViews` inside it.

Comment: @the_UB, is this the best way?

Comment: For me? Yes. Inside Scroll View add a `UIView` and Contraint its all sides to the Scroll View. The added `UIView` is called Content View, as it will contain all the content of Scroll View.

Comment: @the_UB, alright, thanks! I will give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I also face same issue earlier. I resolved the issue by using the tableview instead of scrollview. You can use only one row in tableview and add content there. Tableview easily supports the auto layout.